# Pivot table on the same worksheet with the data

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have created various Pivot Tables but only in other worksheets (inserting new ones) from data. Now, I have the data in the same excel sheet I want to create the Pivot Table. It keeps crushing saying it has problem in the line where I set the PCache.  I am providing the code below

```
Sub a()

Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

Set PSheet = ActiveSheet

LastRow = PSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = PSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = PSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 13), TableName:="PivotTable1"

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Destination")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
    .Subtotals(1) = True
    .Subtotals(1) = False
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Total trucks")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Function = xlSum
    .Name = "Sum of Quantity (cases/sw)"
End With

'PTable.LayoutRowDefault = xlTabularRow
'Range("M2").Value = "Commodity Code"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Replace these lines :

```
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 13), TableName:="PivotTable")

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")
```

With:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
PSheet.Cells(2, 13), TableName:="PivotTable1"
```

And Rename `TableName` to `PivotTable1`

Comment: I just did it and unfortunately, still a problem in the same part! I have uploaded the updated code as it is after the change!

Comment: The only problem is that even if it runs greatly, it says at the end "Unable to set the Name property of the PivotField class... any idea why?

Comment: I will checked later because now I’m in meeting

Answer (score 0):

Read the code below and explanation inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub a()

Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

Set PSheet = ActiveSheet

With PSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)
End With

' first: set the Pivot Cache object
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal))

' Second: set the Pivot Table object
Set PTable = PSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PCache, TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 13), TableName:="PivotTable1")

' after we set the Pivot-Table object, use the object to modify it's properties
With PTable
    With .PivotFields("Destination")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
        .Subtotals(1) = True
        .Subtotals(1) = False
    End With

    With .PivotFields("Total trucks")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 1
        .Function = xlSum
        .Name = "Sum of Quantity (cases/sw)"
    End With
End With

'PTable.LayoutRowDefault = xlTabularRow
'Range("M2").Value = "Commodity Code"

End Sub
```